# Kunze & Hoffman Linear algebra, equivalenece of two homogeneous systems proof verification request

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, solution-verification

I tried to solve the following exercise and would like to know if it is correct and if there is more efficient way to prove it? Any feedback is appreciated.

Chapter 1,
**Exercise 6**

> Prove that if two homogeneous systems of linear equations in two unknowns have the same solutions, then they are equivalent.

*Edit*
Let  $E_1$ denote system $A_{i1}x_1+A_{i2}x_2=0$, where $1\leqslant i \leqslant n$,  and
$E_2$ denote system $B_{i1}x_1+B_{i2}x_2=0$, where $1\leqslant i \leqslant m$.

**Proof**
Let $(a,b)$ be <s>the</s> a solution<s>s</s> of $E_1$ and $E_2$
Then
$\sum_{i=1}^n(a\cdot A_{i1} + b\cdot A_{i2}) =0$,
     $\sum_{i=1}^m(a\cdot B_{i1} + b\cdot B_{i2})=0$.

So
$$\sum_{i=1}^{\max(m,n)}(a\cdot A_{i1} + a\cdot B_{i1}) + \sum_{i=1}^{\max(m,n)}(b\cdot A_{i2}+ b\cdot B_{i2})=0$$

Hence

$$\sum_{i=1}^n(a\cdot A_{i1} + b\cdot A_{i2}) = - \sum_{i=1}^m(a\cdot B_{i1} + b\cdot B_{i2})$$

Hence the systems are equivalent.

Comment: Note (for others on the site): two systems are defined to be "equivalent" in this context if each equation of the second system is a linear combination of equations from the first. In other words, the first can be transformed to the second via row-operations.

Comment: To the asker: it is not at all clear what you mean with $a(\sum_{j=1, i=1}A_{ij}) + b(\sum_{j=1, i=1}A_{ij}) =0$.

Comment: Thanks, added the explanation.

Comment: I'm still confused as to why you are using any $\Sigma$'s at all

Comment: @Omnomnomnom  The $\sum$'s are there because there are n and m systems of linear equations. I did not mention this in original post, so I edited for clarification.

Comment: Your notation is clear now, thanks. What I don't understand is how you took the equation $\sum_{i=1}^n(a\cdot A_{i1} + b\cdot A_{i2}) = - \sum_{i=1}^m(a\cdot B_{i1} + b\cdot B_{i2})$ and decided that this means that the equations are equivalent.

Comment: Also, it is not clear how one should interpret "Let $(a,b)$ be the solutions of $E_1$ and $E_2$"

Comment: @Omnomnomnom In tuple $(a,b)$, $a$ is the value of $x_1$ and $b$ is the value of $x_2$ for which $A_{i1}x_1 + A_{i2}x_2=0$ where $1\leqslant i \leqslant n$.

Comment: So it sounds like you meant to say "let $(a,b)$ be **a solution** (as opposed to "the solutions") to $E_1$ and $E_2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the discussion in the comments, it seems that your solution is incorrect.

Here is one correct approach to the problem.  First of all, we consider $3$ separate cases.

**Case 1:** If *every* pair of numbers solves $E_1$, then it must hold that equations of $E_1$ are of the form $0x_1 + 0x_2 = 0$. If $E_2$ has the same set of solutions, it must also consist of only zero equations, which means that it is equivalent to $E_1$.

**Case 2:** Suppose that the only solution to $E_1$ is $(0,0)$.  Show that $E_1$ is equivalent to the system of equations $E_0$ defined by
$$
1x_1 + 0x_2 = 0, \qquad 0x_1 + 1x_2 = 0.
$$
If $E_1$ and $E_2$ both have $(0,0)$ as their only solution, then we can say that $E_1$ is equivalent to $E_0$, which is equivalent to $E_2$. It follows that $E_1$ is equivalent to $E_2$.

**Case 3:** Suppose that $E_1$ has one non-zero equation, and also has a non-zero solution $x_1 = a, x_2 = b$. Show that $E_1$ is equivalent to the system of equations $E_0$ whose only equation is
$$
-bx_1 + ax_2 = 0.
$$
As before: $E_1$ is equivalent to $E_0$, which is equivalent to $E_2$. It follows that $E_1$ is equivalent to $E_2$.

---

Filling in the blanks:

Useful facts:

1. Any single equation has a non-zero solution
2. If two equations share a non-zero solution, then one is a multiple of the other

This is easy to understand if you think of each solution set to a non-zero equation $Ax + By = 0$ as a line through the origin: any single line contains a point outside the origin, and there is exactly one line between any two points.

A third fact:

3. If $a,b$ are not both zero, then $cx_1 + dx_2$ is a multiple of $ax_1 + bx_2$ if and only if $ad = bc$.

**Case 3:** Because $(a,b)$ is a solution to $E_1$, we have
$$
A_{i1}a + A_{i2}b = 0 \implies A_{i1} \cdot a = A_{i2} \cdot (-b).
$$
By point 3 above, this means that the $i$th equation is a multiple of $-bx_1 + ax_2 = 0$. In other words, every equation in $E_1$ is a multiple of the only equation in $E_0$. Conversely, we that $E_1$ must have a non-zero equation (say the $i$th equation), and the equation of $E_0$ is a multiple of the $i$th equation of $E_1$. So, $E_0$ and $E_1$ are equivalent.

**Case 2:** We want to show that every equation in $E_1$ can be written as a linear combination of the equations in $E_0$, and that every equation in $E_0$ can be written as a linear combination of the equations in $E_1$.

The first statement is easy to show (try it, let me know if you're stuck). For the second statement: we know that $E_1$ has $(0,0)$ as its only solution.  Using points 1 and 2 above, we argue that $E_1$ contains at least two non-zero equations that are not multiples of each other.  In other words, there must exist $i,j$ such that $A_{i1}A_{j2} \neq A_{i2}A_{j1}$ (a convenient way to rewrite $\frac{A_{1i}}{A_{2i}} \neq \frac{A_{j1}}{A_{j2}}$ that still works if one of the denominators is zero).

Let $D = A_{i1}A_{j2} - A_{i2}A_{j1}$. Verify that adding $\frac{A_{j2}}{D}$ times the $i$th equation and $-\frac{A_{i2}}{D}$ of the $j$th equation produces one equation of $E_0$.  Adding $-\frac{A_{j1}}{D}$ of the $i$th equation and $\frac{A_{i1}}{D}$ oof the $j$th equation produces the second.

So, $E_1$ is equivalent to $E_0$.

Comment: I don't understand why is *E_0* of this particular form?

Comment: @flowian The $E_0$'s that I have chosen are convenient choice (but they are not the only possible choices). I recommend that you try to show the things that I tell you to show in the proof-sketch that I have written

Comment: @flowian See my latest edit

Comment: Under point 2, "...solution set to a non-zero equation $Ax + By=0$". What is nonzero equation? 
I'm learning the rest of your answer.

Comment: @flowian I just mean that the equation is not just $0=0$. In other words, $A_{i1},A_{i2}$ are not both zero

Comment: One way for case 2:
$A_{i1}x_1+A_{i2}x_2=A_{i1}(1x_1+0x_2)+A_{i2}(0x_1+1x_2)$.   
 
By the way, how would point 1 under "useful facts" apply to equation $1x_1 + 0x_2=0$ ?

Comment: @flowian When I say that $(a,b)$ is "the zero solution", I mean that both $a$ and $b$ are zero.  So, $x_1=0,x_2=1$ would be a non-zero (or if you prefer "non-trivial") solution to $x_1 + 0x_2 = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

**Case 2**: Suppose that the only solution to $E_1$ is $(0,0)$.
Suppose also that $E_0$ is a set of equations
$$1x_1+0x_2=0, \qquad 0x_1+1x_2=0.$$

Only solution to $E_0$ is $x_1=0,x_2=0$. Since it is also the only solution to $E_1$, the systems are equivalent.

**Case 3**: Since Equations  $E_1$ are homogeneous, there are no non-zero equations, therefore we look at the case where the only non-zero solution is $(a,b)$.

Consider system $E_0$:
$$
-bx_1+ax_2=0.
$$
Solutions to $E_0$ are $(0,0)$, $(\frac1b,\frac1a)$, $(\frac cb,\frac ca),\;c\in \Bbb{C}$.
Let us proceed because I wrote down below part first, and for the sake of correctness.

So we have for system $E_1$
$$
A_{i1}a+A_{i2}b=0 \qquad \text{for any $1\leqslant i \leqslant n\quad$ and $A_{ij}\in \mathbb{C}$}.
$$

Then $E_1$ is equivalent to $E_0$ *iff*
$$
 A_{i1}x_1+A_{i2}x_2 = C_{i}(-bx_1+ax_2),
$$
and 
$$
-bx_1+ax_2=B(A_{11}x_1+A_{12}x_2) \qquad \text{for some $B,C_i\in \mathbb{C}$}.
$$

But since solutions of $E_0$ are $(\frac cb,\frac ca), (0,0)$ (both are not $(a,b)$), the systems $E_0$ and $E_1$ are not equivalent.

Proofs inspired by @Omn in the post above.

**Fact 3**
If $a,b$ are not both zero, then $cx_1+dx_2$ is a multiple of $ax_1+bx_2$ if and only if $ad=bc.$

Let $ad=bc$, and $(a,b)\neq (0,0).$
We have to show that $cx_1+dx_2=E(ax_1+bx_2) \qquad \text{for some scalar E}$.

Let $E=\frac ca$, $E=\frac db$. Then $Ea=c$, $Eb=d$.
Hence $c-Ea=0=d-Eb$.
Now, if $c-Ea$ is scalar of $x_1$ and $d-Eb$ is scalar of $x_2$, then

$$x_1(c-Ea)=x_2(d-Eb) \iff cx_1+dx_2=E(ax_1+bx_2).$$

Comment: @Omnomnomnom ..

Comment: @flovian the system didn't ping me when you wrote that, unfortunately. In any case, I'll take a look when I can

Comment: @Omn that is fine, thank you.

Comment: For case 2, you have assumed that if two systems have the same solution set, then they are equivalent. However, this is exactly what we're trying to prove

Comment: Also, you have misunderstood case 3. The assumption is not that $E_1$ has **only** $(a,b)$ as a solution, it is simply that $E_1$ has **at least one** non-zero solution $(a,b)$, but is not the zero equation

Comment: I'll write in the rest of my proof